# Parse.com does not work with a cellular network

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

I have an iOS app made with Parse.com.

It's working fine using WiFi connection but, when the cellular network is active, parse fails to connect. Of course the cellular network is correctly working and I have no internet problem.

Can someone explain to me? Thank you in advance !

Comment: Any resolution here?  Having same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Goto "Setting" -> "Cellular Network" and check if it's turned on for your application.

[image]

Comment: my app is now working on cellular data using parse, so I think your operator firewall is blocking requests, try on another device, there should not be any problem.

Comment: there is no way to fix that.. to ensure just try on another phone with different provider.

Comment: If my operator firewall is blocking requests, what should I do ? (Anpypic doesn't work either with cellular connection)

Comment: Ok, i will try on another phone. Thank you.

Comment: Try a (free) VPN connection or SSL, which is kind of a general weapon against carrier 'optimizations'.